# How to access Pixy Cam5 data using I2C

Tags: c

Curently I am working in EtherCAT protocol using TI AM437x IDK board. I need to interface a PIXY Camera to identify object. I tried using i2c but I am not getting output. 
Can anyone help me to do this interface. How to get details in Pixy board to my AM437x board using i2c

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's possible.

Comment: In the past there was a somehow similiar question on the [CMUcam board](http://cmucam.org/boards/9/topics/7528), referencing the [protocol used](http://cmucam.org/documents/36). This might answer your question unless you are interested in [I2C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i2c) in more general.